# spring-integration is losing headers when sent to a subscriber

Tags: spring-integration

I am using spring-integration with hornetQ.  The problem is that I have put a custom header in the message (Method), but when it hits the subscriber the header is no longer available.  I there some sort of configuration property I need to setup to preserve headers?

An application receives the message (I can see the `Method` header in the console log so I know it is actually getting the correct message).  It basically just routes the message onto the outbound queue so that client can subscribe to it (if there is a cleaner way to do this please let me know)

```
<int:channel id="partsChannel" />

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="jmsPartsInbound"
    acknowledge="transacted"
    destination-name="parts.in"
    channel="partsChannel"
    connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
    /> <!-- error-channel="partsInboundFailedChannel" -->

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="jmsPartsOutbound"
    destination-name="parts.out"
    channel="partsChannel"
    connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
    pub-sub-domain="true"
    >
    <int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <int:retry-advice max-attempts="3">
            <int:exponential-back-off initial="2000" multiplier="2" />
        </int:retry-advice>
    </int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Applications subscribe like so:

```
   <int:channel id="partsInboundChannel" />

   <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
      id="jmsPartsInbound"
      acknowledge="transacted"
      destination-name="parts.out"
      channel="partsInboundChannel"
      pub-sub-domain="true"
      connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
```

And this is the part that gets the message in the subscriber.

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "partsInboundChannel")
public void processPart(final Message message) {
   ...message.getHeaders does not contain the "Method" header 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't your issue here in the `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper.fromHeaders`:

```
if (value != null && SUPPORTED_PROPERTY_TYPES.contains(value.getClass())) {
                    try {
                        String propertyName = this.fromHeaderName(headerName);
                        jmsMessage.setObjectProperty(propertyName, value);
                    }
```

where `SUPPORTED_PROPERTY_TYPES`are:

```
private static List<Class<?>> SUPPORTED_PROPERTY_TYPES = Arrays.asList(new Class<?>[] {
        Boolean.class, Byte.class, Double.class, Float.class, Integer.class, Long.class, Short.class, String.class });
```

So, if your `method` is really of `Method` type, it will be skipped.

Consider to use its `name` instead.

Comment: You are indeed correct.  I was passing an enum value and it failed to serialize into a string (I would have though it would use the toString() method).  When passing HttpMethod.POST.name() it worked.